# What does "Begin by fixing your existing posts" in the Help Center mean?

Tags: support, help-center, post-ban

I am wondering what "Begin by fixing your existing posts" means in the 'Asking' section of the Help Center.

What if someone deleted their negative voted post? Does it mean that they don't even get a chance to fix their post and can never ask question again on the site?

Comment: Deleted questions are still visible to their original askers, users with 10K+ rep, and mods. So I *think* original askers can still edit their posts.

Comment: what does "users with 10K+ rep, and mods" means ?

Comment: What do you mean what does that mean? "10k === 10,000". Rep === reputation. So, users with 10,000 reputation and above. And mods === moderators.

Comment: does it means only user with 10K+ repo and mods can edit their posts ? Is what is assume from the very first comment.

Comment: "Deleted questions are *still visible to their original askers*"

Comment: I've always understood the "Begin by fixing your existing posts" suggestion to actually mean "You're boned.  You're going to be banned forever"

Comment: In such situation , what should I do. Should I create another account and merge with the current one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you deleted your posts then you can undelete them. And edit them.

You'll find a link to your recent, deleted posts at the bottom of this page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=questions

Comment: I have got this "You have not asked any questions". There are no link for the deleted post. What should I do, should I merge my account with another one ?

Comment: Click on "deleted recent questions", it will be at the bottom of the page, @RahulSharma